# OpenVPN Server Setup

Tags: software-installation, openvpn

I've used OpenVPN Access Server in the past although it seems overkill for a second test server I am setting up.

I am not very familiar with OpenVPN (including Access Server which I had help getting setup).

I wanted to get some advice on setting up OpenVPN on this test server (Not OpenVPN Access Server). OpenVPN is intended to be installed on the test server to allow remote connection to the database running on the server (PostgreSQL) as well as ssh connection to run terminal commands.

I would like to be able to setup the OpenVPN server and generate the client.ovpn config files that I can supply to the client machines (all running OpenVPN client) to allow connection via config files

Is it a process I can run from the servers terminal (CentOS 6.5) with a yum install or is Access Server my only option to allow remote client machines Access to my Server?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated or warnings from people that have setup their own OpenVPN servers

Comment: There's no question in here. What are you trying to do? Is Access Server your only option for what? It sounds like you're having trouble configuring OpenVPN, but configuring it to do what?

Comment: If you're only concerned with creating a secure connection for applications to the database server you could use stunnel instead.  Here's a walkthrough for using it with MySQL, for eg: https://help.knthost.com/mysql-help/using-stunnel-secure-mysql-database. More info on stunnel: https://www.stunnel.org/index.html

Comment: The database and ssh is needed for maintenance. I'm limited to OpenVPN though because all the clients use OpenVPN to make the connection so I need to allow OpenVPN connections on the server, unfortunately it has to be OpenVPN

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is an ordinary Unix daemon, you can run it just fine from the command line. [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) contains an OpenVPN package you can install. You'll then have to write (or copy over) a config file, certificates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go though [OpenVPN HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#quick), it will get you started in no time, except installing. For install on CentOS I'll do:

- install EPEL repo with `yum install epel-release`
- install `openvpn` server with `yum install openvpn`